# List manufacturers with products in category in Magento?

Tags: php, sql, magento, attributes, categories

I'm trying to list (with links) all the manufacturers with products in a specific category. This works:

```
            $category           = 56;
            $layer = Mage::getModel("catalog/layer");
            $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
            $attributes = $layer->getFilterableAttributes();
            $manufacturers = array();
            foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
                if ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'manufacturer') {
                    $filterBlockName = 'catalog/layer_filter_attribute';
                    $result = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock($filterBlockName)->setLayer($layer)->setAttributeModel($attribute)->init();
                    foreach($result->getItems() as $option) {
                        echo '<li><a href="'.$this->getUrl('').'bats.html?manufacturer=' .$option->getValue().'">'.$option->getLabel().'</a></li>';
                    }
                }
            }
```

But when I'm on one of the manufacturer-category pages, the attribute links disappear. I'm assuming because it uses the layered navigation model.

Is there anyway to get a list of manufacturers for a specific category without using the layered navigation model?

Answer (score 0):

Hello i think you create new custom module & override xml tag from catalog.xml to your layout xml

> /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml

call manufacture block with reference name like left/right/content